# Scrapyard Profits in GTA 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've looked everywhere for this answer but I can't find it. I know that destroying cars in GTA 5 nets you the $150. If I just drive vehicles into the ocean does that count as destroying them?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, because that won't be destroying them properly in GTA-V. The only way for it to count towards the scrapyard profits is to actually explode the cars.

> The weekly income depends on you you have to blow up car an easy way to do that is get a tractor trailer truck or another big car/truck and block of the road on both sides. Let car pile up and then use stiky bombs, RPG or a gun to blow up the cars each car you blow up is $150.

---

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/gta5/comments/1mppat/help_how_do_i_make_revenue_with_the_car_scrapyard/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured as much, but couldn't determine for the life of me. Guess I won't waste anymore time driving cars into the ocean! Oh, and the sticky bombs. I'd been using the grenade launcher.